# Adding smooth round Bézier curve corners in unreal editor?

Tags: beziers, unreal-4, unreal

Unreal Editor offers rectangular and round geometry. It also offers boolean operations. I can make a smooth corner by playing around with cylinder and boolean operations. I really would like to make a Bézier curve corner and I need it done quickly in a lot of places (it's not for looks, I actually need it to affect the gameplay and physics) for the rough draft phase.
I also need it to be customizable. I want to be able to change parameters, essentially playing with the three points of a quadratic bezier.

[image]

How could I quickly and effectively add and manipulate round smooth Bézier curve walls / corners in Unreal Editor?

Comment: What have you tried already? What's not working? Please define "quickly and effectively".

Comment: Hi @Byte56 Well, what I am doing right now is wasting time by creating hollow cylinders and stretching them. I am looking for a solution that simply lets me pick three points (start point, control point and end point) and then lets me pick a height and thickness; the result should be a bezier wall. I found [this](https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/Engine/Landscape/Editing/Splines/index.html) but right now it smells like I need a plugin.